# How to give an image from gallery as file parameter

Tags: java, android, image, file, gallery

I am sorry if I am a little hard to understand. I am new to Android. I am trying to make an app to post image and text as status update on twitter. I am following this

http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/

Now here he is giving URL of image and converting it to file and then posting on twitter. I want the user to be able to select image from gallery or take pic from camera and then set as a file in the function. What can I do.? I have added the button to select image and display this in imageview. But how to convert this as a file and pass it to the function.

Here is the class file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Replace your KEY here and Run ,
public final String consumer_key = "trWwomp0b09ER2A8H1cQg";
public final String secret_key = "PAC3E3CtcPcTuPl9VpCuzY6eDD8hPZPwp6gRDCviLs";
File casted_image;

String string_img_url = null , string_msg = null;
Button btn, pick;
EditText et;
ImageView iv;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        pick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onClickTwitt();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showToast("View problem");
            }
        });

    }
}



public void Call_My_Blog(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, My_Blog.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

// Here you can pass the string message & image path which you want to share
// in Twitter.
public void onClickTwitt() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Twitt_Sharing twitt = new Twitt_Sharing(MainActivity.this, consumer_key, secret_key);
        string_img_url = "http://www.bharatbpo.in/bbpo/images/AndroidLogo.jpg";

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        string_msg = et.getText().toString();
        // here we have web url image so we have to make it as file to
        // upload

        // Now share both message & image to sharing activity
        twitt.shareToTwitter(string_msg, casted_image);

    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection Available !!!");
    }
}

// when user will click on twitte then first that will check that is
// internet exist or not
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)     getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo [ ] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


protected void onActivityResult(String requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == "Select Image" && resultCode == RESULT_OK  && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    casted_image = new File(picturePath);
 }            
}
```

Now, instead of this URL of an image, I want the user to be able to click an image or select an image from gallery. Please help. I am not able to upload pictures. Here is the log:

```
09-10 15:26:13.962: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1260): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-10 15:26:18.052: V/log_tag(1260): Pic Upload error403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
09-10 15:26:18.052: V/log_tag(1260): message - Status is a duplicate.
09-10 15:26:18.052: V/log_tag(1260): code - 187
09-10 15:26:18.052: V/log_tag(1260): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
09-10 15:26:18.052: V/log_tag(1260):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=2fc5b7cb or
09-10 15:26:18.052: V/log_tag(1260):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0e8e77fd
09-10 15:26:18.052: V/log_tag(1260): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[2fc5b7cb-0e8e77fd], statusCode=403, message=Status is a duplicate., code=187, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.2}
09-10 15:26:26.262: I/dalvikvm(1260): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
```

Comment: Its just posting the status now. Not the images.

Comment: I am providing different only. I am saying that I am selecting an image and putting some status in the edittext. When I post, the status gets posted but not the image. As if the image was never selected.

Comment: Yes I did, and nothing from there is coming to the log.

Comment: By the way how and from where is the onActivityResult method getting called and when.? I am not able to see anything calling that function.!

Comment: I think its not getting called. Because nothing is coming in the log.

Comment: you are using `RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE` to start activity and in `onActivityResult()` you are using `"Select Image"` thats why its not going inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch an intent to select image from gallery.

Here is a link which you will find useful
http://sudhanshuvinodgupta.blogspot.in/2012/07/using-intentactionpick.html?m=1

Comment: I have already selected the image. How to convert it to a file format which is needed by the function.?